# Inverse of a nonlinear heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

If u solves the equation $$ u_{t} = \frac{u_{xx}}{u_{x}^2}$$

in $\mathbb{R} \times (0,\infty)$and $v$ is the inverse of $u$ in $x$, as in  $y=u(x,t)$ iff $x = v(y,t)$. I need to be able to show that $v$ satisfies a linear PDE.

I've been playing around with the chain rule for a while and can't seem to get anywhere. Either that or I'm applying it wrong. Perhaps there is a different approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right to use the chain rule.
The key equation to remember is
$$x = v(u(x,t),t).$$
Taking $t$-partials of this equation gives
$$0 = v_t(u(x,t),t) + v_y(u(x,t),t)u_t(x,t).$$
We'll hereafter suppress $t$ as a variable. Rearrange to get
$$v_t(y) = -v_y(y) u_t.$$
Taking $x$-partials of the key equation yields
$$1 = v_y(u(x))u_x,$$

or $v_y(y) = 1/u_x(x)$.

Substituting this into the third display yields

$$v_t(y) = -\frac{u_t}{u_x}.$$

Recall that your given PDE is the following:

$$u_t = \frac{u_{xx}}{u_x^2} = -\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big( \frac 1 {u_x}\Big) =  -\frac{\partial}{\partial x}v_y(u(x))
= - v_{yy}(y)u_x(x).$$

Plugging this into the preceding display, finally,

$$v_t = v_{yy}.$$

Comment: Thanks! I eventually got it, but this verifies the result.